# scala how to loop without keeping references

Tags: scala

I have a memory issue in scala in something like the following code:

```
list.foreach(i => {
  val a = new A(a)
  a.doSomething()
})
```

In my example A needs quite a bit of memory and I have a large list of items to iterate. When I do this I get an OutOfMemoryError after a while. I am guessing that a reference to each new instance of A is maintained until the foreach has terminated. So my question then is two fold:

(A) Am I correct in assuming that the each new reference is maintained until the foreach terminates?

and

(B) if this is the case can someone recommend the best way to iterate the list ensuring the reference to the new instance is released after each iteration?

Thanks
Des

Comment: In this case references are not persisted. Are you sure it is not an extremely big object or there is a huge amount of allocations or some other reason? Have you checked your code with profiler? *This seems logical to me giving the functional nature of scala.* Nothing special for scala. Imagine an ordinary java while loop, inside which you're invoking Callable over and over. As soon as you go out of each `call()` current `a` becomes a garbage.

Comment: What is the type of `list`? Is it `Stream`?

Comment: Yes I made an incorrect assumption (making an ASS of U and ME!) and failed to examine the behaviour within my doSomething() which was indeed the culprit that was using too much memory.

Answer (score 0):

I can replicate this with following code on my machine with size of 36. Anything below 36 works fine:

```
  class A(x: Int) {
    val s = "*" * x
    def doSomething() = {}
  }

  (1 to 100).foreach(i => {
    // System.gc()
    val MB = 1024 * 1024
    val size = 36 //30+Random.nextInt(10)
    println(i + " -> Allocating " + size + " MB")
    val a = new A(size * MB)
    a.doSomething()
  })
```

Perhaps that is because of JVM limits on my machine. `System.gc()` also didn't work.

Comment: Calling `System.gc()` is a suggestion and will not force the garbage collector to act.

Comment: @wheaties: Agreed. Thats what I also meant.